# Initial directory is not working for CFileDialog

Tags: c++, mfc, cfiledialog

I am using CFileDialog, I have set the initial path like below , as shown in the code. It's not working . Correct me if I made a mistake.

```
   CFileDialog* filedlg = new CFileDialog(TRUE,(LPCTSTR)NULL ,  (LPCTSTR)NULL , OFN_HIDEREADONLY| OFN_ENABLESIZING , (LPCTSTR)NULL , FromHandle (hImgDlg) ,0 , FALSE  );

   filedlg ->m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir = "C:\\" ;

   if ( filedlg ->DoModal() == IDOK )
   {
       /***  do somthing here *****/
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get compiler errors? Runtime errors or crashes? The initial directory not what you expect it to be?

Comment: Not showing the mentioned initial path it's automatically taken last selected path.

Comment: Are you on Windows 7 (or later), or on an earlier version of Windows?

Comment: Another case to consider is when the lpstrInitialDir is set to a non-existent folder. In that case Windows7 defaults to the most recent folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see the reference for the [`OPENFILENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) structure, you will see that for the `lpstrInitialDir` field it states that:

> If `lpstrInitialDir` has the same value as was passed the first time the application used an `Open` or `Save As` dialog box, the path most recently selected by the user is used as the initial directory.

This means that the `lpstrInitialDir` field can really only be used the first time you use the dialog in a program. The rest of the time it will use the last directory selected by the user.

Comment: Any other alternative API ?

Comment: @user948231 Not that I know of.

Comment: Tanks you @joachim pileborg

Comment: I just stumbled upon the same problem. I really wonder what kind of substance the guy responsible for this strange behaviour has smoked.

Comment: Just got defect request to fix such a behavior in my program, but no idea how to.

Comment: Other than making a dummy CFileDialog and getting its initial directory, is there any way of getting the aforementioned last directory used by the user?

Answer (score 6):

Two options:
1. Old-fashioned dialog style, specifying OFN::lpstrInitialDir

```
CFileLatinDialog dlg (TRUE, "", "" /*lpszFileName */,
   OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,
   "All Files(*.*)|*.*||", this, 0,
   FALSE /*bVistaStyle*/);
dlg.m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir = "C:\\Models\\";
```

2. Vista style dialog, specifying lpszFileName parameter

```
CFileLatinDialog dlg (TRUE, "", "C:\\Models\\" /*lpszFileName */,
   OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,
   "All Files(*.*)|*.*||", this);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you set the filename location, you can get the dialog to open to a specific location.  I would only use this if you really needed the folder location to open or if you have a default filename that you use.

```
CFileDialog* filedlg = new CFileDialog(TRUE, (LPCTSTR)NULL,  (LPCTSTR)_T("C:\\MyFolder\\DefaultFileName.ext"), OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_ENABLESIZING, (LPCTSTR)NULL, FromHandle (hImgDlg), 0, FALSE);
```

or you could use the Windows function `GetModuleFileName`:

```
CString csAppFolder;
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH]; 

// form the path to where we want to store the file
if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH))
{
    PathRemoveFileSpec(szPath);
    csAppFolder = szPath;
}

CFileDialog* filedlg = new CFileDialog(TRUE, (LPCTSTR)NULL, (LPCTSTR)(csAppFolder + _T("\\DefaultFileName.ext")), OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_ENABLESIZING, (LPCTSTR)NULL, FromHandle (hImgDlg), 0, FALSE);
```

Comment: What you suggest is exactly the thing that doesn't work as expected on Windows 7.

Comment: Then I must be doing something further that allows me to get the directory each time I open it.  I don't know what that would be.  But specifying the actual file name on instantiation works.  Its in production and I only develop on Win 7.  I wonder why it is working.

Comment: Why do you specify bVistaStyle=FALSE? In case of Vista Style dialog , specifying lpstrInitialDir  helps

Comment: I will have to give that a try, to see how that affects my app.  Thanks.